# xslt Conditional Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am trying to come up with a xslt that either copies everything from the source xml to target or produce an empty file based on certain value in the source file.

Suppose I have source1.xml, like following:

```
<Order>
  <isDigitalProduct>true</isDigitalProduct>
  <productID>1234</productID>
<Order>
```

and source2.xml, like the following:

```
<Order>
  <isDigitalProduct>false</isDigitalProduct>
  <productID>5678</productID>
<Order>
```

How can I modify my xslt  to evaluate the value of the `<isDigitalProduct>` so that when its value is "true", copy everything as is, and produce a blank output when its value is "false"? For the example above, source1.xml would have its content copied over, whereas source2.xml after the transformation would produce a blank file.

Any help is appreciated!

One more question, what if instead of copy everything I need to transform the `<isDigitalProduct>` element into `<SerialNumber>`. For example, with source2.xml still transforming into empty output while source1.xml be transformed into:

```
<Order>
  <SerialNumber>ABC</SerialNumber>
  <productID>1234</productID>
<Order>
```

Thanx!

Comment: Can you also post the XSL-T you have already tried?

Comment: Re your added question: where did the value "ABC" come from?

Comment: Oh, the "ABC" will be just a fixed random value, so it's safe to assume this hardcoded value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I modify my xslt to evaluate the value of the
>   `<isDigitalProduct>` so that when its value is "true", copy everything
>   as is, and produce a blank output when its value is "false"?

If that's *all* you want to do, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>


<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="Order[isDigitalProduct='true']"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

> One more question, what if instead of copy everything I need to
>   transform the `<isDigitalProduct>` element into `<SerialNumber>`.

In such case, instead of copying the complying `Order` *as is*, you would apply a template to it - and within that template do any required modifications, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Order[isDigitalProduct='true']"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Order">
    <xsl:copy>
        <SerialNumber>ABC</SerialNumber>
        <xsl:copy-of select="productID"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work, but you are very likely to get some errors if the resulting tree is empty...

```
<xsl:template match="Order">
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="isDigitalProduct/text() = 'true'">
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```